# Где хранить строковые ресурсы в Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

задумался над архитектурой клиента и возник вопрос. Где хранить строковые ресурсы сайта. Всякие заголовки, название и прочее. Например в Android для этого есть R.string. А в Angular что делать. Создать для этого отдельный ts файл или использовать имеющийся enviropment.ts? Просто мне кажется странным хранить строковые ресурсы в ts файлах и что делать если мне захочется в будущем прикрутить локализацию на разные языки. Поделитесь опытом.

Comment: В Angular для таких целей используется **i18n**. В [документации Angular Internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview) все подробно описано.

Comment: Спасибо, по ссылке все хорошо понятно в части локализации, но основная часть моего вопроса была, где хранить строковые константы. Если ориентироваться на видео по приведенной ссылке, то блогер хранит строки (основной язык) в файлах  html и ts, где это требуется ему для компонента. Я же думаю, что это плохой тон и как минимум стоит хранить все эти строки в одном месте (как это сделано в андроиде), вот и хотелось бы узнать где у более опытных прогеров на Angular.

Comment: Можете вот тут [https://github.com/ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) посмотреть. Этот модуль позволяет удобно по http подгружать файлы локализации в JSON формате. Думаю - это то, что вы ищете.

Comment: Думаю, это то что нужно, спасибо!